# Using forloop to print an array of strings in c#

Tags: c#

The code below assigns a collection of names to a string, and then uses a foreach loop to display the collection of names within another variable, however it only prints the first name and completely ignores the other 3.
I don't see anything wrong with it though o.O

Heres the code:

```
namespace ForEach
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = { "Jimbo", "UYTR", "MKHH", "Adam" };

        foreach (string person in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ", person);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

}

if anyone could pinpoint where I have gone wrong, I would appreciate it grately.
I seriously think something is wrong with my compiler.

Comment: you're pausing for user input with `Console.ReadLine()`.  Press enter to see the next one ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's not ignoring the other three: it's just waiting for you to input something in the console.

Try:

```
    foreach (string person in names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ", person);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `Console.ReadLine();` out of the loop. Place it at the end.